# How to solve IF ELSE in MIP for inequality check

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Assume I have two variables X and Y, I want to introduce a new variable Z with the following mapping:

IF X NOT EQUAL TO Y THEN Z = 1 ELSE Z = 0

Here, X and Y are both non-negative variables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $X\in [0,M]$ and $Y\in [0,M]$, and introduce two additional binary variables (besides $Z$), $U$ and $V$, together with linear constraints:
\begin{align}
U + Z + V &= 1 \tag1\\
-MU + 0Z + 1V \le X-Y &\le -1U + 0Z + MV \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ forces exactly one of $U$, $Z$, and $V$ to be $1$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces
\begin{align}
U=1 &\implies -M \le X-Y \le -1 &&(X<Y) \\
Z=1 &\implies 0 \le X-Y \le 0 &&(X=Y)\\
W=1 &\implies 1 \le X-Y \le M &&(X>Y)\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank your for your reply. Yes, both X and Y are integers